# group array of object by dates in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Mysql Query:

```
select id, ad_click, contact_submit, MONTH(datetime) as months, YEAR(datetime) years from wpxc_leaderboard_counters order by datetime
```

it's showing result in this way:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 2 [ad_click] => 0 [contact_submit] => 0 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
        ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 3 [ad_click] => 0 [contact_submit] => 0 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
        ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 4 [ad_click] => 1 [contact_submit] => 0 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
        ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 5 [ad_click] => 0 [contact_submit] => 1 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
        ) 
        [4] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 1 [ad_click] => 3 [contact_submit] => 2 [datetime] => 2019-12-06 
        ) 
    )
)
```

but wanted to show in this way:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [11] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 2 [ad_click] => 0 [contact_submit] => 0 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
            [id] => 3 [ad_click] => 0 [contact_submit] => 0 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
            [id] => 4 [ad_click] => 1 [contact_submit] => 0 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
            [id] => 5 [ad_click] => 0 [contact_submit] => 1 [datetime] => 2019-11-01 
        )
        [12] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 1 [ad_click] => 3 [contact_submit] => 2 [datetime] => 2019-12-06 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Hope this is possible with modifying array as i have used different methods and spent lots of time but nothing achieved yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a substring of the date as an array key as you fetch the query results.

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
    $result[substr($row->datetime, 5, 2)][] = $row;
}
```

The array you showed doesn't quite match your query. If you're already selecting MONTH in the query, you won't need to use `substr`. You can use

```
$result[$row->months][] = $row;
```

I also suggest you consider grouping by the year as well as the month for future sorting purposes, but this probably won't matter for now since your query is ordered by datetime. It depends on how you intend to use the grouped data, but if you include year as part of the key you can be sure the groups will always sort properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it helps me to build logic which was quite straight forward, I was just got stressed and unable to get the proper logic and here's what i got:

$items = array();
foreach($sql as $row) {
    $items[$row->months][] = $row;
}